# Limits of an indeterminate form $\lim_{t\to\infty} (a+b(-m)^t)/(c+d(-m)^{t-1})$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I'm trying to solve the limit of the following indeterminate form:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{a+b(-m)^t}{c+d(-m)^{t-1}}$$

where $t=1, 2, 3, \cdots$ denotes time and all the coefficients are positive rational numbers.

In particular, I would like to consider two cases: i) $0<m<1$ and ii) $1<m$.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where you got this problem ?

Comment: @AakashKumar: It is a model I built in my own work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

i) $0\lt m\lt 1$

Since $-1\lt -m\lt 0$, we have $(-m)^{t}\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.

ii) $1\lt m$

Since $-1\lt\frac{1}{-m}\lt 0$, we have $\frac{1}{(-m)^{t-1}}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. Now, divide both the numerator and the denominator by $(-m)^{t-1}$.

Comment: I have made a slight revision and some clarification. Can you please help me once again? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: @ppp: Ah, I didn't notice the issue. See the addition in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! You used l'hopital's rule, right? But according to the definition of l'hopital's rule, it cannot be applied in my case as both numerator and denominator have to converge to either zero or infinity, no?

Comment: @ppp: No, we don't need the rule. For the first, the limit is $\frac{a+0}{c+0}=\frac ac$. For the second, the limit is $\frac{0+b(-m)}{0+d}=-\frac{bm}{d}$

Comment: So the point is that the limit operator can be separately applied to each relevant term in the numerator and denominator, right?

Comment: @ppp: Yes because we can do that in our case.

Answer (score 0):

if $m>0$ we have $-m<0$ and if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ what kind of number is $$(-m)^{x}$$?
in this form makes the limit no sense.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/659914)

Comment: why not? $(-m)^x$ is not defined for $-m<0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$!!

Comment: for example calculate $(-3)^{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Yes, I know it's not defined. But when a question doesn't make sense you comment on it, you don't try to answer it.

Comment: Edit made to replace $x$ with $t$, discrete time index and to clarify that all the coefficients are positive rational numbers.